# convert a single client socket program to multi clients program

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, tcp, client-server

i wrote a server and a client in python. I am running it in 2 different vms, the program is kind of a quiz game- the server sends questions to the client and the client answers. I am trying to convert the program to multi client program, so that the server will be able to get up to 3 connections from the client (3 separate terminals in the client machine). I get resourceIO errors and I cant make that 2 request with 2 different ports will get connected to the server
this is my server code (I cut off the logic of the game):

```
MAX_CLIENTS = 3
CURR_CLIENTS = 0

class ClientData:
    def __init__(self, conn, addr):
        self.conn = conn
        self.addr = addr
        self.money = 0
        self.phase = 0
        self.life_saver = True
        self.question_num = 0
        self.chaser_phase = 0
        self.status = 1
        
def initialize_client_data(client_data):
#logic of initialize data

def handle_client(client_data):
    while True:
        print(f"[NEW CONNECTION] - {client_data.addr}")
        client_data.conn.send("Welcome to the game!\nDo you want to play? y/n \n>>".encode())
        connected = True
        while connected:
            msg = client_data.conn.recv(1024).decode()
            if msg:
                print(msg)
            if msg == 'n':  
                connected = False
                client_data.conn.send("Bye Bye".encode())
                client_data.conn.close()
            else:
                initialize_client_data(client_data)
                phase_A(client_data)
                    while (client_data.status == 1):
                        #logic of checking if game over
                
def send_question(client_data):
    #logic of sending the question string to display it in the client screen

def chaser_answer(client_data,question_num):
    #logic of random answer for computer

def client_answer(client_data, question_num):
    #logic of sending a question and get an answer in return 

def phase_A(client_data):
    #phase A cut off

def phase_B(client_data):
    #phase B cut off

def start():
    global CURR_CLIENTS
    server.listen()
    print(f"Listening on ", (host, port))
    while CURR_CLIENTS < MAX_CLIENTS:
        try:
            conn, addr = server.accept()
            CURR_CLIENTS += 1
            print(f"[ACTIVE CONNECTIONS] {CURR_CLIENTS}")
            conn.setblocking(False)
            data = types.SimpleNamespace(addr=addr, inb=b"", outb=b"")
            events = selectors.EVENT_READ | selectors.EVENT_WRITE
            sel.register(conn, events, data=data)
            client_data = ClientData(conn, addr)
            thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(client_data,))
            thread.start()
            print(f"[ACTIVE CONNECTIONS] {threading.active_count() - 1}")
        except BlockingIOError:
            pass

host, port = sys.argv[1], int(sys.argv[2])
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((host, port))
server.setblocking(False)
sel = selectors.DefaultSelector()
sel.register(server, selectors.EVENT_READ, data=None)
start()
```

Comment: As an aside: A streaming socket doesn't guarantee any message boundaries. `client_data.conn.recv(1024)` could receive part of a multibyte character and the decode may fail. You need to buffer input and catch decode exceptions to handle that.

Comment: There are many ways to parallelize a server. Its frequently something you design in from the beginning. In your case, the easiest way to do it may be to create a thread after each `accept` to do all of the client specific work.